# Automate switching icons for Xamarin.Forms application?

Tags: xamarin.forms, icons

We have a single project that is used by 2 different clients.

The Apple store won't let us use the same icon for both, so we need to build version A with Icon set A, and then the same code as version B but with Icon B.

Do you see any way to automate switching the icons?

Comment: Note that we are building via appCenter, and so scripts might be a possible answer.

Comment: You could use same Icon with two apps in app store, but app name and package name is different. you need to make sure their bundle IDs are different.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** For you to be able to upload your application on the App store it is mandatory that the App name and the Bundle id(package name) of these applications are different.

Now there is a catch Apple might or might not reject your app if it has the same resources as another. (They can be confusing at times).

I would suggest you do not take a risk change the icons, and you will have to change the app related things in any case.

> Do you see any way to automate switching the icons?

I don't think there is an automated way but there is a faster way, make a list of the images that you need to change with the sizes and name of that images as per your resource files, Once you are ready with all the images directly replace them in the resources by pasting them over the existing ones and replacing them.

Once you are done with that clean build your app and your resources are freshly changed and ready to rumble.

Goodluck!

Revert in case of queries.